# Braintree rejects Discover cards on consecutive transactions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, braintree, braintree-rails

**Background**

We are executing the below method in order to charge a user and store his/her information in Braintree vault:

```
def store_in_vault
  Braintree::Transaction.sale(:amount => amount,
  :credit_card => {
    :cardholder_name => cardholder_name,
    :number => credit_card_number,
    :expiration_date => "#{credit_card_expiration_month}/#{credit_card_expiration_year}",
    :cvv => credit_card_cvv
  },
  :customer => {
    :id => user.id,
    :first_name => user.first_name,
    :last_name => user.last_name,
    :email => user.email,
    :phone => user.phone_main
  },
  :billing => {
    :first_name => user.first_name,
    :last_name => user.last_name,
    :street_address => street_address,
    :extended_address => extended_address,
    :locality => city,
    :region => state,
    :postal_code => zip,
    :country_code_numeric => country
  },
  :options => {
    :submit_for_settlement => false,
    :store_in_vault_on_success => true
  })
end
```

Later, we also put a hold on user's credit card as a security deposit.

All works well for most of the credit cards. However, when we try to put such security hold on **Discover** cards our transaction gets rejected with "Processor Declined" or "Declined" error. Note, that the initial transaction above to store user account in vault and charging credit card executes successfully. Just the later security hold transaction gets rejected.

**Questions**

Why this behavior happens only to Discover cards? How to fix it?

Comment: I am a developer at Braintree. This issue can be related to how your Discover account configuration is set up. I recommend emailing our support team at [support@braintreepayments.com](mailto:support@braintreepayments.com) so they can take a closer look at your account.

Comment: @KathrynExline: Thanks! Talking to support is in process. Though, I was hoping that someone has had this issue. And I doubt that it is related to our account. Most likely it depends on some requirements from Discover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is somehow related to Discover cards verification process. They require CVV and zip code to be included in transaction.

As per Braintree support :options in the above request have to include :add_billing_address_to_payment_method => true as follwoing:

```
:options => {
  :submit_for_settlement => false,
  :store_in_vault_on_success => true,
  :add_billing_address_to_payment_method => true
}
```

In addition, during credit card replacement request (if required), one should add :billing_address information:

```
Braintree::CreditCard.create(
  :customer_id => "#{user_id}",
  :number => cc_number,
  :expiration_date => "#{expiration_month}/#{expiration_year}",
  :cardholder_name => cardholder_name,
  :cvv => cvv,
  :billing_address => {
    :street_address => street_address,
    :extended_address => extended_address,
    :locality => city,
    :region => state,
    :postal_code => zip
  },
  :options => {
    :make_default => true
  }
)
```